# How i Implement Role Based Access Control in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, permissions, role

Currently I'm working on an ERP project. I want to set the Roles & Permissions via a RESTful Api. I'm using Mongodb and Nodejs. How can i implement this?

**Roles & Permissions are as follows:**-

> Level 4 Access - Covers all employees like mechanics, supervisors,
>   etc. Can access only certain features.
>
> Level 3 Access - For Unit managers - Can access all features but
>   require permission to edit / change.
>
> Level 2 Access - Admin - Can Edit / change / add almost all features
>
> Level 1 Access - Master Admin - Can edit / change / add all features

Comment: please show your efforts

Comment: Without knowing your detailed use cases/user stories, functional and non-functional requirements, resources and whatnot this question is impossible to answer. Or pretty easy: Use what suits your requirements and resources best.